# Changing Disk Encryption key in CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos6.4, disk-encryption

I checked the "encryption" checkbox in the Anaconda installer during CentOS 6 installation, which encrypts at the PV (Physical Volume) partition level.

Now, for some security reasons, I want to change the current encryption key.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default encryption method uses [LUKS](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/), so issue:

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda
LUKS header information for /dev/sda2

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        512
MK digest:      ec 80 b6 a6 f4 b6 23 29 d6 22 53 2c af c6 a6 06 01 ca 7c 34
MK salt:        97 4c c5 fe 39 e5 ec f7 3c 7a a5 bd 98 34 56 b4
                0d c4 cc c2 ab 74 fa 5c bd d3 0f e3 ae 65 c3 d7
MK iterations:  59625
UUID:           d8bfb76f-fec3-4d6e-8801-5ab24517c081

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             238801
        Salt:                   42 37 13 4d 6f d5 eb e6 10 dc 78 c8 04 f9 10 74
                                48 15 4d e0 68 d5 dc 7f 6a 14 66 a2 88 83 4f 17
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

to see how many slots you are currently using. Replace `/dev/sda` with the appropriate block device.

Add a new key to a free slot using `cryptsetup luksAddKey`, check the possible options in the [`cryptsetup(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) manpage.

Afterwards, reboot and ensure you can access the machine using the new key. Then you can delete the old one (`cryptsetup luksRemoveKey`).